# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions when trying to make a component using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error and I am unable to solve this :-   Line 6:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './BurgerGraphic.module.css';
import BurgerIng from './BurgerIng/BurgerIng';
const BurgerGraphic = (props) => {
    return
    (
        <div className={classes.Burger}>
            <BurgerIng type="bread-top" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default BurgerGraphic;
```

Comment: U don't use `props`. You can remove it and return `div` directly, without return keyword and scopes.

Comment: parenthesis of return is on the next line, JavaScript syntax does not support this.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript requires the value of the return to be on the same line as the return itself.

This can be worked around by opening parentheses on the same line as the return and then entering the return value within them over multiple lines.

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './BurgerGraphic.module.css';
import BurgerIng from './BurgerIng/BurgerIng';
const BurgerGraphic = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Burger}>
            <BurgerIng type="bread-top" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default BurgerGraphic;
```